# Getting error "t1 cannot be resolved as a variable" in t1.addView()

Tags: java, android

i am new to android and i dont know how to use addView(). i am not able to figureout the error in the code. (All other files in the app are working properly except this one.)
      tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
This is the line where I am getting error and it says "t1 cannot be resolved as a variable. and i have no clue what to declare it as.. Please help me.

```
public class example extends Activity {

    private static String url = "http://nissarcs.net78.net/android/example.php";
    private static final String TAG_Assessments = "Assessments1";
    private static final String TAG_CODE = "COURSE";
    private static final String TAG_CNH = "COURSE_NAME";
    private static final String TAG_CR = "CR";
    private static final String TAG_CT = "CT";
    JSONArray degree = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tablemain);

        tl.addView(tr_head.new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Integer count = 0;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            degree = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Assessments);
            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < degree.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = degree.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing each json item in variable

                String code = c.getString(TAG_CODE);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_CNH);
                String cr = c.getString(TAG_CR);
                String ct = c.getString(TAG_CT);

                TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                if (count % 2 != 0) tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                tr.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 2);
                tr.setId(100 + count);
                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                //Create two columns to add as table data
                // Create a TextView to add date

                TextView labelCR = new TextView(this);
                labelCR.setId(200 + count);
                labelCR.setText(cr);
                labelCR.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                labelCR.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                labelCR.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                tr.addView(labelCR);

                TextView labelSC = new TextView(this);
                labelSC.setId(200 + count);
                labelSC.setText(code.toString());
                labelSC.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                labelSC.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                labelSC.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                tr.addView(labelSC);

                TextView labelACTIVITY = new TextView(this);
                labelACTIVITY.setId(200 + count);
                labelACTIVITY.setText(name.toString());
                labelACTIVITY.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                labelACTIVITY.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                labelACTIVITY.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                tr.addView(labelACTIVITY);

                TextView labelSAT = new TextView(this);
                labelSAT.setId(200 + count);
                labelSAT.setText(cr.toString());
                labelSAT.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                labelSAT.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                labelSAT.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                tr.addView(labelSAT);
                // finally add this to the table row
                tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_CODE, code);
                map.put(TAG_CNH, name);
                map.put(TAG_CR, cr);
                map.put(TAG_CT, ct);
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Proper indentation would be nice.

Comment: what is t1, write definition of t1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tl` here looks like a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#TableLayout%28android.content.Context%29)

Try using:

```
 TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablemain);
```

Answer (score -1):

issue is

```
tl.addView(tr_head,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```